# Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate: get the resulting SQL query with parameters substituted

Tags: sql, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to get the final SQL query that is sent to the database from `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = :name;
```

I need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name ='mark';
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide more context information, try towards a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at the source code of the [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java) will show that all the queries get through [`getParsedSql()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6902ff77d9f30bcc6dbbac11b7479293ce566fe9/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java#L435) method and the [`NamedParameterUtils`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterUtils.java) for parsing.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = :name;
```

Will probably get translated to something like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = ?;
```

And the parameter will be provided as a separate object, because that's how JDBC works.

If you just want to inspect the statements you can add some breakpoints and take a look. If you want to actually obtain the values you can change the code, to make it accessible, either by reflection or by actually using your own version of `NamedparameterJdbcTemplate`.

Note that you won't probably see what you expect.